# vmware not showing changes

Tags: magento-1.9

I am running magento on VM and i have set it up on my neatbean in save on FTP mode. However whenever i make changes it is getting saved into server rightly which i verified by opening file on filezilla as well. however modification is not visible on site untill i restart my virtual machine. It is becoming very hard for me to debug like this as for every echo, print_r i have ot restart my VM to see changes. Can anybody point out what is going wrong?

Comment: Do you have any caching enabled?

Answer (score 0):

The problem does not come from your VM.
I am running many Magento installations on many VMs and there is no problem. It seems that you have enabled Magento Cache system.

Try clearing the cache of magento(not your browser) and then you'll see the changes!

Comment: I have tried that as well. Also in my system cache is disabled.but no luck.